# Printing map layers in pdf format using leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, pdf

I'm working with leaflet api to print map layers one by one. the output should be a pdf file with several pages, I want that in each page there will be a map (layer over a basemap)  on the right and a writing on the left. Is there a plugin that allows it with the ability to customize the output?
this is an exemple : [image]